# Dynamically making a link from an URL string in db table to a HTML/PHP page

Tags: php, html, url, anchor

I am trying to make a PHP page that fetches results from a MySQL db table on a server (www.domain.com).

The table has the following fields:

```
ID    (ie: 1)
Date  (ie: 2014-12-06)
Text  (ie: Guns 'n Roses)
URL   (ie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx)
Link  (ie: Watch on YouTube)
```

The URL is anchored in Link text to a webpage.

My query is easy and straightforward: a simple `select * from table`. When run, PHP page prints on screen the following table:

```
2014-12-06 --- Guns 'n Roses --- Watch on YouTube
```

where, by clicking on "Watch on YouTube", the actual address becomes:

`www.domain.com/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx`

How can I get rid of the server root and have a working link?

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<div id="youtube">

<?php

require "parameters.php";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Date, Text, URL, Link FROM $db.$table_10 ORDER BY date desc");

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Text</th><th>Link</th></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td></br></td></tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$safe_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['URL']);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "&#160;&#160;</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Text'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=" . $safe_url . " " . "target="."_blank".">" . $row['Link'] . "</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for replying and helping me !

Comment: Show exactly the code dumping the `SELECT` results please.

Comment: You will need to show us how your PHP/HTML looks like in how you're retrieving the data. It's not about "how to get rid of", it's about using the proper syntax.

Comment: It seems to me that question title is wrong

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL or databases. The problem is about dinamically making a link from an URL string.

Comment: Are you perhaps using some kind of framework that automatically builds all your links as relative to your domain?

Comment: in your markup, you may have accidentally used the form `<a href="/$URL">` when you should be using `<a href="$URL">`

Comment: @sean9999, removing slash in his template will likely solve the problem (but title is still wrong)

Comment: @vladkras: true. @Wailmanager, you should remove tag `MySQL` and add `HTML`, and change your question so that it reflects the nature of the problem. Also, show some code so people can help you

Answer (score 3):

If a link isn't prefixed with a protocol it becomes relative to the page containing the link.

```
<a href="example.com/somepage">Webpage</a>
```

becomes http://example.net/example.com/somepage when clicked

```
<a href="http://example.com/somepage">Webpage</a>
```

becomes http: //example.com/somepage

When you're displaying the link, prefix it with http://

-

Here's a JSFiddle showing this, http://jsfiddle.net/7fnpg5o1/

Comment: I'm sure he has https, look at his example attentively

Comment: Yes, URLs are correctly prefixed